# CSS color fade on select

Tags: css, select, fade

Im new to programming but trying to write a piece of css and getting stuck with a fading effect on an element.

I'm trying to change the subscription widget (top right) on my wordpress site so that it is styled to look like the search widget below it.

http://magmamachine.co.uk/blog

I'm trying to get the background of my input fields to fade a different color when the user selects them. - like the search field does below.

so far I have this:

```
.sky-form-orange .input:hover input{
background-color: #f5b093 !important;
}
```

Which changes the effect on hover.

Is it possible to change this to fade when selected and not hover?

regards
mike

Comment: I think you're looking for the transition property: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

Comment: Your question gets even better, if you add the relevant `HTML` parts to it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `background-color` and `transition`, you get a smooth fading effect.

I've added a border to demonstrate that the transition works with multiple values.

```css
.sky-form-orange .input input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.sky-form-orange .input input:focus {
  border-color: red;
  background-color: #f5b093;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sky-form-orange">
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`focus` is the css selector for inputs that are active.

Try using `:focus` as the selector for your input:

```css
    .sky-form-orange .input input:focus {
        background-color: #f5b093;
    }
```

```html
<div class="sky-form-orange">
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

...although I'm not sure as to the HTML structure but it should give you some idea!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the CSS `:focus` selector:

```
.sky-form-orange .input:focus input{
    background-color: #f5b093 !important;
}
```

this has more details: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

Comment: vote down for link to w3schools also answer was already posted

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use CSS3 transition:
you learn how to use it from link bellow:
[CSS3 Transition](http://www.css3.info/preview/css3-transitions/)

Comment: The first correct answer. The following link also explains it very well: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/